# Vue how to test a child component inside a slot

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-test-utils, vitest

I am using Vue Utils and I want to test a sub component inside a slot. I have a main component and inside this component, I have an empty template. in this template I would place  my sub component. If the dense property in Component A true is, then it will be also true in component B.

when I do the console log, I don't get the component B and I get the whole time a warning that in Component B, it is expecting a string, and instead of a string it is false

```
Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "value". Expected String, got Boolean with value false.
  at <ComponentB dense=undefined value=undefined  ... >
  at <VTUROOT>
```

example:

```
<componenta>
    <componentb/>
</componenta>
```

my approach was first to use shallow Mount and ten inside the slot just add , this don't seem to work.

```
const mountTestComponent = (
  dense?: boolean,
) => {
  return mount(ComponentA, {
    props: {
      dense,
    },
    global: {
      stubs: {
        ComponentB: {
          template: '<span />',
        },
      },
    },
  })
}

let wrapper = mountTestComponent()

describe('ComponentA.vue', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = mountTestComponent()
  })

  it('is dense', async () => {
    wrapper = mountTestComponent(true)
    console.log(wrapper.html())
  })
})
```

and in the console log I get:

```
<div class="ComponentA" >
  <!-- @slot Use this slot for the component. -->
</div>
```

Comment: It's not shown where componentb comes from. If it's not global comp then it's stubbed incorrectly

Comment: You have to provide a slot when mount the component https://test-utils.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/slots.html